# How can I multiply fields containing both natural values and currency?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, field, multiplication

I'm trying to replicate a calculator from my Excel spreadsheet to a webpage.
The first field is an input to natural numbers (without commas), the second is to some currency values (with commas, points, etc) and the third is the total, but it has a defined value (for example, 0,38 cents). Both of the fields must multiply and give a result in the third field.

I tried to create a mask using a mask plugin, but had several errors. Tried to use toLocaleStrings too.

I'm having problems with the masks and the results.
That's the expected result :
[image: capture]

HTML

```
<form>
<!-- simple number to start the calculation -->
<label>Natural Number</label>
<input type="text" id="base" />
<br>
<!-- currency including the cents -->
<label>Currency value</label>
<input type="text" id="ticket" />
<br>
<!-- If the first field is "1" and the second is "1,00", this field has a value of 0.38 cents. -->
<label>Currency total</label>
<input type="text" id="cost" readonly /></form>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#cost').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});

$('#base').keyup(calculate);
$('#ticket').keyup(calculate)

function calculate(e) {
$('#cost').val($('#base').val() * $('#ticket').val() * 0.38).trigger('input')
}
```

});

Comment: Can you show us the expected currency value format? Did you tried with Maskmoney https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney... Please add the expected format in  your question

Comment: I added an example of a result in the post. I tried a maskMoney and in fact is a more efficient mask. But sometimes the Total currency doesn't show the decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regex to parse out all the non digit and decimal symbols.
The toDigits function below accomplishes just that and allows you to use regular math after that.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //add maskMoney listener
  $('#base').keyup(calculate);
  $('#ticket').keyup(calculate);
});

function calculate(e) {
  const percent = 0.38,
    baseValToDigits = toDigits($('#base').val() || 0),
    ticketValToDigits = toDigits($('#ticket').val() || 0),
    costVal = baseValToDigits * ticketValToDigits,
    percentageOfCostVal = costVal * percent;
  //format percentageOfCostVal as currency
  $('#cost').val(percentageOfCostVal).trigger('input')
}
function toDigits(val) {
    const isNeg = /(\(.*\))|^[-]/.test(val),
        digits = parseFloat(val.toString().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
    return isNeg ? digits * -1 : +digits;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <!-- simple number to start the calculation -->
  <label>Natural Number</label>
  <input type="text" id="base" />
  <br>
  <!-- currency including the cents -->
  <label>Currency value</label>
  <input type="text" id="ticket" />
  <br>
  <!-- If the first field is "1" and the second is "1,00", this field has a value of 0.38 cents. -->
  <label>Currency total</label>
  <input type="text" id="cost" readonly />
</form>
```

Comment: It worked to the calculation, and i used maskMoney to the decimals, but the total doesn't show with the mask, unless I click with the cursor.

Comment: i have modified the above code. either you can add back in your maskMoney listener or you can properly format the value before you set the cost field's value. see comments in the above code for both options

Comment: Thank you. Everything work. But i think that maskMoney have some limitation because i always must click at the result to see the decimals.

Comment: if this is mask money by jquery i did find a blurb: IMPORTANT: if you try to bind maskMoney to a read only field, nothing will happen, since we ignore completely read only fields. So, if you have a read only field, try to bind maskMoney to it, it will not work. Even if you change the field removing the readonly property, you will need to re-bind maskMoney to make it work.

Comment: I don't know if i understood well. I've already removed the 'readonly' from the input. But it doesn't matter because the field just show the currency format when i select it.

Answer (score 0):

It's functional here without any plugins. Something you could customize to fit to your actual project. Hopefully the next HTML standards would finally bring inline localization to input fields.

---

[UPDATE] Using a less delayed Onchange instead of keyup event handlers, would allow easier typing and become more user-friendly. And allowed typing using comma that would be replaced to the default expected dot so that parseFloat function would treat it as a valid number.
So we could use a regex pattern to format the currency value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('form').on('change','#base,#ticket',function() {
  var ticket=parseFloat($('#ticket').val().replace(',', '.'));
  calculate();
  if(!isNaN(ticket)){
  $('#ticket').val(EuroFormat(ticket));
  }
  });

function calculate(e) {
var ticket=parseFloat($('#ticket').val().replace(',', '.'));
var total = parseFloat($('#base').val()) * ticket * 0.38;
if(!isNaN(total)){
$("#cost").val(EuroFormat(total));
}

}

function EuroFormat(num) {
  return (  num.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1.') + ' €'  ) 
} 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<!-- simple number to start the calculation -->
<label>Natural Number</label>
<input type="text" id="base" autocomplete="off"/>
<br>
<!-- currency including the cents -->
<label>Currency value</label>
<input type="text" id="ticket" autocomplete="off"/>
<br>
<!-- If the first field is "1" and the second is "1,00", this field has a value of 0.38 cents. -->
<label>Currency total</label>
<input type="text" id="cost" readonly"/></form>
```

Comment: That's a very good option.But i don't know if the users can type fast.
obs. I'm also waiting for an inline solution to HTML.

Comment: Using dot instead of comma is already an issue to me :) in my country we use only comma for decimals... Yeah that should be added to locals!

Comment: I just updated it using onChange event which is more user-friendly in this situation

Comment: Thank you. Totally more friendly. But the ticket value is not accepting the cents.

Comment: It does ! well that's the issue with javascript I mentioned above... you need to type using a dot :) I do remember finding a workaround to that for a client in an invoice form. I'll see what I can do

Comment: It's done now ! The ticket value accepts a comma as a decimal separator

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Number.toLocaleString('en-us',{minimumFractionDigits:2,maximumFractionDigits:2})+'€'` to get your desired currency format.

```js
const curr=v=>isNaN(+v)?'':(+v).toLocaleString('en-us',{minimumFractionDigits:2,maximumFractionDigits:2})+' €';
var d={};
['base','ticket','cost'].forEach((id,i)=>{
  d[id]=document.querySelector('#'+id); 
  if(i<2) d[id].addEventListener('change',ev=>{
    var tv=parseFloat(d.ticket.value.replace(/,/g,''));
    d.cost.value=curr(d.base.value*tv*.38);
    d.ticket.value=curr(tv);
  });
})
```

```html
<form>
  <!-- simple number to start the calculation -->
  <label>Natural Number</label>
  <input type="text" id="base" />
  <br>
  <!-- currency including the cents -->
  <label>Currency value</label>
  <input type="text" id="ticket"/>
  <br>
  <!-- If the first field is "1" and the second is "1,00", this field has a value of 0.38 cents. -->
  <label>Currency total</label>
  <input type="text" id="cost" readonly />
</form>
```

Although I am still a big fan of jQuery, I have written the above in Vanilla JS. It is simple enough ...

Comment: Vanilla is good enough. But in this case, the ticket is not in currency format.

Comment: There are many ways of dealing with that: either print the currency symbol *behind* the input field (as part of the label) or - as I have just done in my answer - "allow" it in the field itself by placing it there and ignoring it during processing. You could of course "force" it back after each editing of the value, but as I have my action triggered by the keyup event this would cause havoc. So, in my sample I simply accept values with and without a currency symbol.

Comment: Actually, the symbol is not important, but the decimals are. I need the commas and points in the second field to make it similar of an excel spreadsheet and its formatting currencies.

Comment: Ok, I have changed the trigger event from `keyup` to `change`. This makes it possible now to apply the currency-postprocessing `curr()` to both, `#ticket` and `#cost` input fields. Maybe this is what you want?